# No text area in JOptionPane window

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, joptionpane

Is there anyway to have a JOptionPane window without the text area but with only a scroll bar,

```
JTextArea listBox = new JTextArea(aLineFromFile);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(listBox);  
    listBox.setLineWrap(true);  
    listBox.setWrapStyleWord(true); 
    scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scroll, "Dictionary enteries", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

I don't want the white background behind the text I just want the scroll bar.
Or anyway to make the text in the text area uneditable.

Answer (score 0):

"Or anyway to make the text in the text area uneditable."...

Try:

`listBox.setEditable(false);`

Also, you might be better off using a JLabel rather than a JTextArea.